# Best practice when rolling back to the last commit in a branch

Tags: git, tfs, rollback, git-revert

So, I made a bad commit, and merged it into my `test`-branch, and found out it didn't work.

The appropriate action, in my opinion, would be to roll back the `test`-branch, and deploy it again. But how I do that, without loosing the rest of my work?

I usually work with TFS (newest version), but it could also be just on my local machine it happened.

[image: Commit flow]

**Edit**: This is what I fear might happen (see below). 
A coworker makes a commit, and merges it in, and his code breaks because mine didn't work.
And it could take hours, days, weeks before I make the last commit. 
So I need to roll it back to not break other's work as well.

*Git Flow* is not a magic word I'm after, since we just share the `Developer`-branch.

[image]

Comment: Just merge again

Comment: Merge develop onto test.  There's no need to modify the history of the test branch.  You should re-deploy after you've moved the test branch forward.

Comment: I'm curious.  What do you mean by 'rolling back'?  To me, that phrase means to redeploy an older version of the software and has nothing to do with modifying the history of the git repo.  You can 'revert' or 'rebase' or 'reset' a branch, but you don't 'roll back'.

Comment: @WilliamPursell - please see the update with clarification :)

Comment: @mrtux - please see the update with clarification :)

Comment: @WilliamPursell - I need the merge from ``Develop`` to be undone. it must perish from the history, so no one will take it and think it works.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are asking for *best practice*, here's an advice:

- Do not rewrite history.

  - Fix the issue and merge it instead.
- If it is important for you that a given branch only ever contains a known-to-work copy of your code, you **really** should look into Continuous Integration, and only ever allow merges into your precious "Test" branch if the CI-build succeeds.

  (there's a number of git-based project management systems, like GitLab or GitHub that either have CI-support built-in or have a tight integration with 3rd party CI-providers).

Comment: That is a good advice. What if the code builds, and no test will catch it? It could be a visual part...

Comment: then you need to create a test that will catch it. the test *can* be executed by a human, who must manually approve the merge request. In any case, keep in mind that for non-trivial code **no** test-suite will ever be able to catch **all** the bugs beforehand, and consequently you will always ship somewhat buggy code.

Comment: And it's not possible to reverse cherry pick the commit, or somehow pull it out to redeploy?

Comment: it's certainly possible, but it's not best practice.

Comment: Let's say I find the error as soon as I put it up, and I estimate it will take a few hours (too long) to fix it. How can I remove the merge commit?